# php button call a php function

Tags: php, function

I have that code to create a button

```
$button = "<input type='submit' id='liga' value='liga'>";
echo $button;
```

I have the php function

```
function liga(){
....}
```

as I do so by clicking the button it calls the function?

Using html this code works, but I really need use the php button, how can I make it?

```
<input type="submit" name="liga" value="liga" />
if (isset($_REQUEST['liga'])) {
    liga();
} elseif (isset($_REQUEST['desliga'])) {
    desliga();
}
```

Comment: `Server side` here and waaaaayyyyy over here is the `client side` and between those 2 is a big gab!

Comment: You say using html the code works but you need to use the php button - what do you mean? Typically PHP creates HTML when you are talking about tags like a button...

Comment: I need create multiple buttons and want insert the button names the values of php variables

Comment: Do you still want the button displayed after it is pushed?

Comment: after is pushed call function liga() only this

Answer (score 0):

This little snippet will take an array with the index being the name of the button and the value as the label the button should have. It will then make a button for each element of the array.

```
<?php
$foo = array('name'=>'label', 'name2'=>'label2');
foreach ($foo as $k=>$v)
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"$k\" value=\"$v\" />\n";
?>
```

You can also put the PHP variable right inside the HTML code using `<?=...?>`:

```
<input type="submit" name="<?= $myPhpVar ?>" value="<?= $myOtherPhpVar ?>" />
```

Or you can put complicated expressions (or whole programs) using the typical `<?php...?>` tags inside HTML brackets - whatever it `echo`d becomes the content of that html tag:

```
<input type="submit" name="<?php echo $myPhpVar; ?>" value="<?php echo "LABEL: ".$myOtherPhpVar; ?>" />
```

Comment: none of the answers, I need to make this line work  when I click it don't open the function   $button = "<input type='button' id='php_button' value='liga' onclick='liga()'>";   The event onclick don't work

Comment: Looks like @Rizier123 had it right in the beginning. You need to understand the difference between client side and server side. The server runs PHP and sends a file (usually HTML) over the client. The client displays it in the browser and handles your UI (such as clicking a button). But you have to send the results back over the server (usually by submitting a form) in order to do anything with a PHP script again.  [This page](http://tut.php-quake.net/en/communication.html) might help you to understand.

Comment: `onclick="liga()"` is a JAVACRIPT (NOT PHP!) function. So you have put the name of a PHP function in there, but your browser doesn't know PHP; it only knows javascript. It can't find that function name and so javascript crashes silently (probably) for this page but you won't see this unless you have the javascript console open.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='liga' value='Liga'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='desliga' value='Desliga'>";
```